# Explain how Read/Show works?

Tags: haskell

Can someone please explain how Read/Show works.. I cannot find any tutorials on it. I've been searching through crappy haskell documentation for 4 days now and i'm getting very frustrated.

Could someone please be a savior tonight and help me convert a int to a string so I can reverse the string value.

Thank you.

Edit.. adding my current code..

```
mult_add d s = d + 10*s

form_number_back d = foldr mult_add 0 d

form_number_front d = reverse[(show $ read (form_number_back(d)))]
```

Comment: You should not use `show` and `read` for this. Try to think of another way. (You have all the pieces already!)

Comment: You are seeing something i'm not.. it could be because i've been bashing my head against this code for about an hour. The obvious thing to do would be to reverse what mult_add did.. but I have NO IDEA IN THE WORLD how to do that since its embedded 3 deep in the function.
form_number_front d = form_number_back((-10)*d)

Comment: update if you are still there.. trying this.. 
form_number_front d = (form_number_back(d) - (10*d)) still no luck..

Comment: No, do not reverse what mult_add does. Reverse the list `d`.

Comment: As a side note, when you have a technical question, and you ask it, we'll happily help you. The repeated appeals to pathos ("I've been working on this for four days", "I have a 15-hour work day tomorrow", "my teacher sux", "my teddy bear isn't soft enough", etc.) are unnecessary.

Comment: @ sdcvc i've tried putting reverse EVERYWHERE, do you mind explaining what should be happening. I just don't see it at all. if d = [1,2,3,4] then I shove d into form_number_back which returns [4321] I have to reverse that returned value... I just don't understand this at all.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, just beyond frustrated with this language, its getting late and I really just want to figure this out. Very sorry.

Comment: @user1449653 If shoving `[1,2,3,4]` down `form_number_back`'s throat doesn't get you the answer you want, you have three choices: don't use `form_number_back`, massage the answer it does give you, or shove something different down its throat. Try the last one.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could include a few examples of desired output from some given input. From what I gather, what you want is a function `f` such that `f 123` evaluates to `"321"`, is that correct? If so, should `f 890` be `"98"` or `"098"`?

Comment: I understand that the expected output of `form_number_back` is `321` for an input `[1,2,3]`. What is the expected output of `form_number_front`? Is it `123`? You should include this information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` converts a string to an Int (in your case), whereas `show` converts an Int to a string.

It looks like `form_number_back` returns an `Int`, so you just need to `show` it, not `read` it.

Also, `show` returns a string (in your case, `[Char]`) so there's no need to put another `[...]` around the result.

Answer (score 4):

Writing types out will help.

```
 mult_add :: Int -> Int -> Int
 form_number_back :: [Int] -> Int
 read :: [Char] -> Int
 show :: Int -> [Char]
 reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question appears to be part of a running dialog between you and some other folks here on SO - which is fine by me - but trying to answer you question without the rest of the context is hard beyond suggesting you see the Learn you a Haskell tutorial on the topic:

http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses

Comment: I have been reading through documentation on Haskell for 4 days now. I'm so beat up on Haskell code. I dont think anymore context is needed. I'm trying to finish this off so I can have some piece of mind and a good sleep tonight before 15 hours of school. I have been reading that though and I appriciate the link. None of it explains why reverse won't work (found that out through here), or any of the other things i've asked. For those documents to be relevent you have to understand whats going on. Which my teacher hasn't done and the books have failed at. Stackoverflow is my last hope.

Comment: I wasn't talking about you needing context, I was saying I would need to understand the context and what issues you've been having to be able to help you.  I think you need some rest and suggest IRC as a good place to get real time help.

Comment: I do need rest but cant get any until this is done sadly. I also cannot get into IRC because I need 20 pts or something. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm talking about irc.freenode.net - not StackOverflow IRC.  There's typically 700 people (most idling, mind you) at #haskell and a good number of more specific channels using Haskell for this or that.  Where are you studying anyway?

Comment: @user1449653: When you have the time, do read the first couple of (or preferably all) chapters from learnyouahaskell. It is a very good introduction to Haskell. Reading the first three chapters should get you to a position where you can easily solve the problem in your question.